# Sum SQL statement outputs many rows when I expect only one

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I have 3 tables joined as shown:

[image]

What I want to do is query for the sum of all the holdings that fall into the criteria specified for the clients in my query. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT Sum(Holdings.HoldingValue) AS SumOfHoldingValue
FROM (Clients INNER JOIN Accounts 
    ON Clients.ClientID = Accounts.ClientID) 
    INNER JOIN Holdings 
    ON Accounts.AccountID = Holdings.AccNum
GROUP BY Holdings.HoldingDate, Clients.Active, Clients.RiskCode, Clients.NewClient, Clients.BaseCurrency, Clients.ClientID
HAVING (((Holdings.HoldingDate)=#3/31/2013#) 
    AND ((Clients.Active)=True) 
    AND ((Clients.RiskCode) In (1,2)) 
    AND ((Clients.NewClient)=True) 
    AND ((Clients.BaseCurrency)='GBP') 
    AND ((Clients.ClientID) Not In (10022,10082,10083)));
```

Here's an example of what I get as the result:

```
SumOfHoldingValue
1056071.96
466595.6
1074459.38
371142.54
814874.42
458203.65
8308697.09
254733.94
583796.33
443897.76
203787.11
1057445.84
1058751.26
317507.43
```

So there are quite a few criteria for the client table but the result is a list of `SumOfHoldingValue` when what I want is just one number. I.e. the sum of all the holding values. Why is it not grouping them all together to form one total?

Comment: Add the following to the select statement:  Holdings.HoldingDate, Clients.Active, Clients.RiskCode, Clients.NewClient, Clients.BaseCurrency, Clients.ClientID

Comment: Given that you're `GROUP`ing, you could include those `GROUP` columns in the `SELECT` list without affecting the query overall. You'd then see that the different rows have different values for `RiskCode` and/or `ClientID`.

Comment: OK, it's because `ClientID` and `RiskCode` has different values. How can I group everything even if they are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not computing any aggregates on the values in the `HAVING` clause, I think you just want this:

```
SELECT Sum(Holdings.HoldingValue) AS SumOfHoldingValue
FROM (Clients INNER JOIN Accounts 
    ON Clients.ClientID = Accounts.ClientID) 
    INNER JOIN Holdings 
    ON Accounts.AccountID = Holdings.AccNum
WHERE (((Holdings.HoldingDate)=#3/31/2013#) 
    AND ((Clients.Active)=True) 
    AND ((Clients.RiskCode) In (1,2)) 
    AND ((Clients.NewClient)=True) 
    AND ((Clients.BaseCurrency)='GBP') 
    AND ((Clients.ClientID) Not In (10022,10082,10083)));
```

Which, with no `GROUP` clause will produce a *single* `GROUP` (over the entire set) and produce a single row.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want totals - remove the group by. With the group by clause it gives you totals for every group separately.

If you need to filter data put the condition into Where clause instead

Answer (score 2):

Your query contains a `group by` clause which returns each group on its own line.

You are also using a `having` clause.  The `having` clause is applied *after* the `group by`.  Usually, it would contain aggregation functions -- such as `having count(*) > 1`.  In your case, it is used as a `where` clause.

Try rewriting the query like this:

```
SELECT Sum(Holdings.HoldingValue) AS SumOfHoldingValue
FROM (Clients INNER JOIN Accounts 
    ON Clients.ClientID = Accounts.ClientID) 
    INNER JOIN Holdings 
    ON Accounts.AccountID = Holdings.AccNum
WHERE (((Holdings.HoldingDate)=#3/31/2013#) 
    AND ((Clients.Active)=True) 
    AND ((Clients.RiskCode) In (1,2)) 
    AND ((Clients.NewClient)=True) 
    AND ((Clients.BaseCurrency)='GBP') 
    AND ((Clients.ClientID) Not In (10022,10082,10083)));
```

Comment: @harryg . . . No problem.  It is not that uncommon for more than one person to arrive at the right answer for a question.